# Making a "if x in dict(json)" statement with handlebars.js

Tags: javascript, html, json, django-templates, handlebars.js

I am trying to covert a Django template to a Handlebars.js template. In the django template I used:
 `if forloop.counter in Dinsdag`
 I'm trying to make a custom helper in Handlebars.js that does the same thing. This is what I have so far:

helper.js:

```
Handlebars.registerHelper('isIn', function(waarde, inWaarde){
   $.each($.parseJSON(inWaarde), function(k, v) {
        if (k == waarde){
            return options.fn(this);
        }
   });
    return options.inverse(this);
});
```

data.js:

```
$(function(){
    var templateScript = $("#entry-template").html();
    var theTemplate = Handlebars.compile(templateScript);
    var context = {  "dinsdag": {
                        "uitval2": {
                          "7": "1",
                          "9": "1",
                          "11": "1"
                        },}}
    var html = theTemplate(context);
    $('.test').html(html);
    $(document.body).append(html);
})
```

index.html:

```
<html>
<head>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/handlebars.js/4.0.5/handlebars.min.js">
     </script>
     <script type="text/javascript" src="
https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.0.0-beta1/jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="helper.js"></script>
    <script src="data.js"></script>
 </head>
<body>  
   <script id="entry-template" type="text/x-handlebars-template">
       <ul class="test"> 
           {{#dinsdag}}
                    {{#isIn 7 uitval2}}
                        <p>klopt</p>
                    {{else}}
                        <p>mwah</p>
                    {{/isIn}}
           {{/dinsdag}}
       </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</script> 
</body>
</html>
```

This doesn't put anything on screen, and gives the following error:
`Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token o`

Hoping that someone could help. Keep in mind that I'm a total noob at Handlebars.js

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the problem was that Handlebars "stringifies" `JSON` automatically.
removing `$.parseJSON` didn't solve it though, I had to specify that it was `JSON` to `jQuery`.
 I did this like this:
`$.each($.parseJSON(JSON.stringify(inWaarde))`